# .NET MAUI application running on an android emulator gets an HTTP request error

Tags: android, dns, android-emulator, maui

I have a fairly simple .NET MAUI application that I'm currently testing on an android emulator. The app itself runs fine, but the emulator uses HTTPClient to reach out to a live website that runs on our company's website, for the sake of simplicity I'll just call it https://api.company.com/api/token.

About 3 days ago the requests were working fine, I was able to get a token no problem. Yesterday it started happening intermittently that I would get the error "One or more errors occurred. (Unable to resolve host "api.company.com": No address associated with hostname)". Today its happening each time I try.

We reach out to a separate API for different information, again for simplicity I'll just call it https://api2.company.com, and I get the same error for it

I'm able to access the endpoint no problem with Postman, so I don't think its the endpoint. I did do some research and I think the issue is with the android emulator. I went through and checked everything I could find
-The emulator has wifi enabled
-The androidmanifest.xml has internet permissions
-I played around some with the emulator's DNS settings, namely running .\emulator.exe -avd api_33 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
-using the IP of the API rather than the domain name
-Downloading a fresh emulator
-Using a different emulator

Nothing seems to be working, is there something that I'm missing? From the research I've been doing it almost seems like it's got something to do with how my app handles DNS, but thats a little outside of my wheelhouse. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you open the URL in the browser of your android emulator?